# How to extract HTML from PHP files?

Tags: php, asp.net, html

I have a bunch of PHP files, from which I want to extract the final HTML result. For example if the PHP file content be something like:

```
<ul id='<% echo($newsListId) %>'>
   // PHP loop to create <li> elements
</ul>
```

What should be extracted is:

```
<ul id='news-list'>
   <li>First News</li>
   <li>Second News</li>
   <li>Third News</li>
   <li>Fourth News</li>
</ul>
```

What should I do? Is there a software which can do that for me?

Note: There is no dynamic content in PHP files. In other words, no connection to any external database is made in PHP files. Actually, these PHP files belong to a template I downloaded from somewhere and now I want to change their language to something else (like ASP.NET for example).

Answer (score 3):

It would be easiest to install a local apache on your machine (Like `MAMP` or `WAMP`), and then build a PHP script that would loop over the folder structure and read each file with `file_get_contents()` through the server.

If you try to read myFile.php , you will get the source,
But if its parsed through the server first, meaning - reading http://localhost/myFile.php , will returned the parsed result from PHP.

Shai.

Comment: ...or, if you have PHP installed but not a web server, you could `exec("php myFile.php",$result); $result = implode("\n",$result);`... and +1.

Comment: Agreed, also a great solution, you don't actually need to install Apache or any other webserver, just a standalone installation of PHP will do the trick. Even though I do think it would be somewhat easier with a webserver, for someone not experienced:)

Comment: Agreed, having a web server installed is definitely the easiest way to guarantee that you get sensible HTML results - executing via CLI might result in some oddities from values in `$_SERVER` not being defined correctly (or at all), amongst other potential hazards.

Answer (score 1):

run php files on your server in order to get the result, then view source in browser and copy and paste the output

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can echo them into an output buffer (PHP code):

```
ob_start();
include('your_file.php');
$contents = ob_get_clean();
```

now `$contents` hold the parsed contents of that file and you can write it into another file with:

```
file_put_contents('filename.html', $contents);
```

cheers!

Comment: This would be a very bad solution if we're talking about many files. If this "bunch" of files is 200-300 PHP files, I don't think including all of them in a single PHP file is a good solution.

Comment: We're not including them alltogether, this solution fills and clears a buffer (aka. memory = blazing fast) while parsing the files. It wouldn't take a minute for 200 - 300 files.

Comment: Taking back what i said :) Not a bad idea at all! I like the idea behind approach, even though I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: @ShaiMishali I request you to delete the comment which raises concern about memory as it has become absolute due to your latter comment. It adds to confusion.